# Case Statements with Any

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some `E_ids` which are linked to a couple of `d_ids` and with `o_count` in any of `(1,0,null)`.
So if any of the `E_IDs` have an `O_count = 1`, I have to club it into one row and write the `O_count = 1` for that `E_ID else 0`.

But when I do the below, I get all the rows without the grouping, i.e, I get two rows of the same `e_ids`. Is there any other way to do the same?

```
SELECT DISTINCT E_ID, status
  (CASE WHEN o_count = any(1) THEN 1
        WHEN o_count = any(0) THEN 0
   ELSE null END
  ) Ocount 
FROM (SELECT e_id, status, o_count FROM A)
GROUP BY e_id, status, o_count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just wrap it with `MAX()` :

```
SELECT E_ID,status
        MAX(case when o_count = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as Ocount 
FROM A
GROUP BY e_id,status
```

Also , the sub query was unnecessary , you are not doing any logic in there.

Comment: Actually i'm joining two tables in that sub query. This is just part of the entire query. Tried making it a bit easy to explain. :) 
Even doing this does not help. I'm still getting two rows with the same id.

Comment: @Pri Oh my bad, forgot to remove it from the group by , now will work.

Comment: Yes this works. Yay! Thank you so very much. I was struggling with this. I cannot up vote now because i'm new to Stack Overflow. Will do ASAP :)

Comment: You should remove the superfluous `DISTINCT`. And `MAX(case when o_count = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END)` gives you zero in case you only have a null entry. If this is desired you can shorten this to `NVL(MAX(o_count), 0)`, if not use `MAX(o_count)`.

Comment: @sagi : Is there a way i could display all the column values(EG: D_ID) with the count of a column(Eg: count(D_ID) )? The count will be grouped by T_ID etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you group by `e_id, status, o_count`. That means you aggregate your data such that you get one row for each such combination. Don't you rather want to get one result row per `e_id` alone or maybe `e_id` plus `status`?

Then you have that `case` construct not containing any aggregate function, but only the `o_count` which is part of your `group by` clause. So you are looking at one row where you want `o_count = any(1)` which is exactly the same as `o_count = 1` of course, because there is only one value in the specified set. You can replace the complete `case` expression with a mere `o_count`.

Then you apply `distinct`. But there can be no duplicates, as you are grouping by all columns used. So `distinct` doesn't do anything here.

Selecting from a subquery without any `where` clause or aggregation is also superfluous and you can select from table `a` directly.

Your query can be re-written as

```
select distinct e_id, status, o_count
from a;
```

I suppose you want something like this instead:

```
select e_id, status, max(o_count)
from a
group by e_id, status;
```

Or this:

```
select e_id, max(status), max(o_count)
from a
group by e_id;
```